# added item to state but can't render

Tags: reactjs

I managed to add Item to the list but can't render it.
My App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      recipes: [{
      ...sample data...
      }]
    }
  }

  createRecipe(recipe) {
      this.state.recipes.push({
        recipe
      });
      this.setState({ recipes: this.state.recipes });
  }

  render() {
     ...

export default App;
```

and my RecipeAdd:

```
export default class RecipeAdd extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        url: '',
        title: '',
        description: '',
        error: ''
    };
  }
```

...event handlers...

```
  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.state.url || !this.state.title || !this.state.description) {
      this.setState(() => ({ error: 'Please provide url, title and description.'}));
    } else {
      this.setState(() => ({ error: ''}));
      this.props.createRecipe({
        url: this.state.url,
        title: this.state.title,
        description: this.state.description
      });
    }
  }
    render () {
      return (
        <div>
           ...form...
        </div>
      )
    }
}
```

In React dev tools I see the recipe is added with 'recipe'. How should I change my createRecipe action to add new recipe properly? :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're wrapping the recipe in an extra object. You can see in your screenshot that index 3 has an extra `recipe` property.

It should be more like this -- just `.push` the recipe object directly:

```
createRecipe(recipe) {
  this.state.recipes.push(recipe);
  this.setState({ recipes: this.state.recipes });
}
```

Even better would be to not mutate the state object directly, by using `concat` instead:

```
createRecipe(recipe) {
  this.setState({
    recipes: this.state.recipes.concat([recipe])
  });
}
```

Comment: `.concat` will return a new array, so it's good to avoid this. It's basically the same as creating a copy of the array and pushing on to it. The above code should work, just need to remember that the parameters need to be arrays, so you need to wrap it in an array to use it.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!